# How to make my FFT library code work? It's spitting out complete wrong frequencies

Tags: arduino, fft

so I'm a first year eng student and I have no idea how the algorithm works, I understand what it does but in terms of math I just trust my soul with the library.

Im trying to make my microphone ("High Sensitivity Microphone Audio Amplifier Module Output 20dB Gain Low Noise DC 3.3V/5V Sound Sensor") pickup sounds and output the frequency so I can make a guitar tuner (yes i looked online at the 1000+ solutions). The thing is, whatever sound I make, it keeps outputting 60ish Hz for some reason. The code is below and yes the wiring is correct:

````
#define SAMPLES 128 
#define SAMPLING_FREQUENCY 2048  

arduinoFFT FFT = arduinoFFT();  
unsigned int samplingPeriod; 
unsigned long microSeconds;  

double vReal[SAMPLES]; 
double vImag[SAMPLES];  

void setup() {   
      Serial.begin(115200);   
      samplingPeriod = round(1000000*(1.0/SAMPLING_FREQUENCY)); 
}  

void loop() {  
     for(int i=0; i<SAMPLES; i++)    {     
           microSeconds = micros();     
           vReal[i] = analogRead(A0);    
           vImag[i] = 0;      

           while(micros() < (microSeconds + samplingPeriod))     {   
             // do nothing
           }  
       }   

FFT.Windowing(vReal, SAMPLES, FFT_WIN_TYP_HAMMING, FFT_FORWARD);   
FFT.Compute(vReal, vImag, SAMPLES, FFT_FORWARD);   
FFT.ComplexToMagnitude(vReal, vImag, SAMPLES);    
double peak = FFT.MajorPeak(vReal, SAMPLES, SAMPLING_FREQUENCY);   
Serial.println(peak);    

delay(100); 
}```
````

Comment: Do you live in a country where electricity runs at 60Hz?

Comment: It’s plugged in to my usb via arduino

Comment: Yes, but is your country electricity running at 60Hz?

Comment: im in canada so yeah

Comment: Now you know where the 60Hz peak comes from.

Comment: why is it picking up frequencies from the electricity and not my extremely loud guitar strums